# Kotlin data class instanciation via reflection

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection

I am writing a small data access layer for our application connecting to MongoDB and I want to instantiate queried entities to (domain model) data classes automatically using reflection

I have seen people talking about JSON deserialization to Kotlin data classes and I see why that would be an option due to MongoDB returning data in the related BSON format. However, I want to abstract over that data source.

So given a map of field names and values of arbitrary type, how can I define a function `toDomain` so that it takes such a map and the target class `Class<T>` as parameters and spits out a `T` as result? I am stuck because the `newInstance()` method invokes the (nonexistent) default constructor and the arity and types of my data class constructor arguments vary so I can't "hardcode" this information either.

Edit: I want to clarify that I do not want to know about any libraries I can simply plug into my code (except if they are open source and have a readable implementation) but instead I want to learn about the possibilities I have with reflections in this regard.

Comment: Can you add an example code with the `newInstance()` method? I mean the class that has that method...

Comment: @BartekLipinski Currently I accept `clazz: Class<T>` as parameter where T is an arbitrary domain model data class. However data classes must have at least one constructor argument so `clazz.newInstance()` fails since there is no default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`KClass<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) (if you get a `Class<T>` from other code, `clazz.kotlin` gives you the `KClass`). It contains the information you need, should be something like (based on your own answer)

```
fun <T> Document.asInstanceOf(clazz: KClass<T>): T {
    val constructor = clazz.primaryConstructor!!
    val args = constructor.parameters.map { param ->
        this[param.name, param.type.jvmErasure.java]
    }
    constructor.call(*args)
}
```

You'll need to add `kotlin-reflect` to your dependencies to use this (not `KClass` by itself, but much of its power).

Comment: what is Document what is the import statement look like for it?

Comment: It comes from the asker's code, so you need to ask him.

Comment: But I guess this one http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html.

Answer (score 4):

I found a somewhat functional solution. When compiling I supply the `-parameters` flag in my Kotlin gradle build script:

```
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
```

then the following piece of code works:

```
fun <T> Document.asInstanceOf(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    val constructor = clazz.constructors.first()
    val args = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for (param in constructor.parameters) {
        args.add(this[param, param.type])
    }
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return constructor.newInstance(*args.toTypedArray()) as T
}
```

as the runtime knows about the names of my constructor parameters hence I can do a direct mapping. This is not the final version, just a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for data classes, probably others, as well.

```
// Supply the args in the primary ctor's declaration order.
inline fun <reified T : Any> createThingy(vararg args: Any?): T =
    T::class.primaryConstructor!!.call(* args)

    @Test
    fun testCreateThingy() {
        data class Datum(
            val x: Int,
            val y: String
        )
        assertEquals(Datum(96, "tears"), createThingy<Datum>(96, "tears"))
    }
```